# how to define function prototype with object and key parameters

Tags: typescript

I am trying to define a helper function that will parse an axios error and store the resultant error message into the specified field of the specified object.

I want the calling site to be:

```
axios.get(...).then(...).catch(ParseIntoErrorString(myClass, 'loadError');
```

where `myClass` is a TypeScript class that contains a method that is calling this code (probably from a 'loadData' method). `myClass` will likely be replaced with 'this' in most cases.

`loadError` is the name of a string property on `myClass`. I am modeling this after `jest.spyOn`, where you specify the object that you want to spy on and then the string argument is the name of the function you want to replace with a spy function. `jest.spyOn` has a nice property that it will give you an error if you provide a string that isn't a function of the spied on object.

I have tried something like this, but it isn't working at all:

```
type NonFunctionPropertyNames<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? never : K }[keyof T] &
  string;

export function ParseErrorIntoString<T extends {}, P extends NonFunctionPropertyNames<Required<T>>>(obj: T, member: P): (reason: AxiosError) => void {
  return (reason: AxiosError): void => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
    obj[member] = AjaxParseError(reason);
  };
}
```

The `NonFunctionPropertyNames` was lifted right from the jest typings file.

And besides not working at the call site, this code itself throws up two errors:

1. it complains that I can't use extends {} and suggests that I replace it with `Record<string, unknown>`, which is fine, but when I do that, I can't pass `this` to it at the call site because it says that `this` doesn't conform to `Record<string, unknown>`. It doesn't tell me why.
2. the `obj[member]` says that I can't store a string into it. I suspect this is because there is no restriction of the `NonFunctionPropertyNames` that limits it to only allow string properties.

I have also tried this:

```
export function ParseErrorIntoString<T extends object>(obj: T, member: Extract<keyof T, string | null>): (reason: AxiosError) => void {
  return (reason: AxiosError): void => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
    obj[member] = AjaxParseError(reason);
  };
}
```

My expectation is that `Extract<keyof T, string | null>` will select all of the keys of T that are of type "string | null".
But it does not. It does give me an error at the calling site if I pass in a non-member in the string, but it is too accepting. It will also allow me to provide the name of a boolean member without throwing an error.

Which is probably why it still throws an error at the `obj[member] = ...` line, saying that I can't assign a string to `obj[member]`.
Also, I have to explicitly state T at the calling site for it to accept a member of T. I was assuming that like `spyOn` in jest, it would infer the type of T from the first argument.

Here is a more stand alone full example. This is the third attempt that is getting very close:

```
class cls {
  public str: string | null;
  public bln: boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.str = "";
    this.bln = false;
  }
}
   
const instance = new cls();

type StringPropertyNames<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string | null ? K : never }[keyof T] & string;

function f<T extends cls>(obj: T, p: StringPropertyNames<T>): void {
  obj[p] = "done";
}

f(instance, 'str'); // I want to be able to call f, with the instance and the property like this
console.log(instance.str) // should print out 'done'
```

in this complete example, `f` is the original `ParseErrorIntoString` function.
In this third example, the calling site of `f(instance, 'str')` works as expected. I get an error when I try to call `f(instance, 'bln')` because bln is type boolean, not type string.

But I am still getting "Type 'string' is not assignable to type `T[StringPropertyNames<T>]`" on the obj[p] = 'done' line.

I think the `StringPropertyNames<T>` needs to be given some sort of return type to say that it is only returning keys of type string | null.

Any suggestions on the proper typing of the `ParseErrorIntoString` function?

Comment: Does this question depend on axios and jest?  If so, do you want to edit the tags to include these?  If not, could you [edit] the example code to be self-contained so that it demonstrates your issue when pasted into a standalone IDE (so, either remove or define third-party values/types)?  In either case you should remove typescript-typings because it's not appropriate (I don't even know why that tag exists anymore since it's about a particular deprecated package, but I don't have the power to destroy it)

Comment: @jcalz, it does not depend on axios or jest. The third version is self contained and fails on the string assignment line within the function. This standalone code was tested in https://www.typescriptlang.org/play

Comment: Perhaps a link to the playground with this code preloaded would not be amiss, too help potential answerers by preloading a known-good IDE with settings as desired?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WKObyW) meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Pls mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply)

Comment: @HereticMonkey here is a link to the playground I have been using https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwArwPaXqAcgIYC2EAzgDwAqAfFALxQDeUA2gNJQpQDWEIWAGZQqAXQBcIjqKgQAHsAjIAJmShkEKVFAA+UZAFcANkagB+KJ0nIIANwjwoAX1Z8BwsQG4AUN8EHkAGNgRCxkKEFqWQUlVShAozIaAAosACMAK0kqABooMEk4JDRMHAcCEnJqGgBKSVssRGVmbyg2qHSM1jAZRgAiZTCIPp8nX28EwjI1BLUmVvyDNKNEQPUESQ1i7T1DEx82sCWVteXkSTSsLCMIQmQfBcCwrYNgrHhkmpb2qGAAC0QZAAdFsGFA+iMFm1-oCgWcwYJCIkIAdnL42mQIMAilpPswoFCIhRZikYWQ8gByLYUmoLMZjdoTZ7ALjIDR3QLQRg2ADu8USnx8gmSKHZQQglOpNQeTzZ1wgQKMWFQIrZwA5Cq2tPGQA

Comment: @jcalz Wow that does seem to work. Your approach comes at it from a different direction than all the other stuff I have been using to try to solve it. Thank you!

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've run into a current limitation or missing feature of TypeScript, documented at [microsoft/TypeScript#48992](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48992).  You'd like to say `KeysOfType<T, string | null>` to mean "the keys of type `T` whose properties have type `string | null`" and then use those keys to read/write `string | null` to/from a value of type `T`.  There are ways to do this when `T` is some specific type, but when you're dealing with generics the compiler is unable to follow the logic when actually trying to read/write properties.  That is, when `T` is generic, the compiler has no idea that `T[KeysOfType<T, string | null>]` is compatible with `string | null`, no matter how you define `KeysOfType`.

Until and unless this is implemented and we have a native `KeysOfType` that the compiler understands, the workaround I usually use is to reverse the constraint.  Instead of a generic object type `T` and keys of type `KeysOfType<T, string | null>`, use a generic keylike type `K`, and then define your object type in terms of it like `Record<K, string | null>` (using [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) to say a type with keys of type `K` and values of type `V`).  The compiler *does* understand that `Record<K, string | null>[K]` is compatible with `string | null`:

```
function f<K extends string>(
    obj: Record<K, string | null>,
    p: K
): void {
    obj[p] = "done"; // okay
}
```

And this works on your example code:

```
f(instance, 'str'); // okay
```

---

That's it, mostly.

There are other quirks you might run into around the difference between reading and writing (you really only care that you can write `"done"` to `obj[p]`, not `string | null`, but it's hard to express that in a way that the compiler accepts) and [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) (if you call `f({...}, 'str')` with some object literal `{...}` the compiler might complain about the object literal having properties that are *not* `str`), but those are out of scope for the question as asked.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCIwN4FgBQ0PQA4FcBGIAlsNBAC4BOAXKZYQHYDm0APtPTiCANxqbb4iJAvRp4A9uJABTMPV6o+mYOPrkKOYGXEUAFAEpoKdP0xkAFoQgA6ddAC80AEROFps5ZsiH0AGZgEaTdMAF80MMVUFTUyaAZyOWBpH3ppAHc4BAMFNFzUXxx6LUJVPwAeAGloaQAPMml6ABMYdQZGAD5dJQxxPAArGgAlaRUKRsqAGloKNtZ2ThB2ie7sGgq0fRoAN3FCRqMV3r6AbSwAXR8nRtVpV3C83114skTpKYBydXf9bmgAej+0HEAGswABPNDRCBSaTWEDiRhPGKvWyUQwA0jmcScfZYGb0WLY2Lva6pd55IA)